# What is $\partial_i f(Ax)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be an n-dimensional square matrix, $f$ a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

I found the result
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\partial_i f(Ax) = \sum_k\partial_k f(Ax) A_{ki}
\end{equation}

and want to show that its true.

My approach is to use the chain rule on $$f(Ax) = f((Ax)_1, (Ax)_2, ..., (Ax)_n)$$ where $$(Ax)_k = \sum_jA_{kj}x_j .$$

I get $$\partial_i f(Ax) = \sum_k\frac{\partial f((Ax)_1, (Ax)_2, ..., (Ax)_n ))}{\partial(Ax)_k} A_{ki}$$

which seems not to be the same as (1).

Comment: I can only see the difference in notation, not in substance.

Comment: So do you mean that $\frac{\partial f(Ax)}{\partial (Ax)_k} = \frac{\partial f(Ax)}{\partial x_k}$ ? Its not obvious to me that this is true.

Comment: No, but I realized that the statement of the problem is ambiguous: it uses $\partial_k$ for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ on the left and for $\frac{\partial f(Ax)}{\partial (Ax)_k}$ on the right. Your answer is less ambiguous, and can be made even clearer by using $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ in the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion is mainly caused by (bad) notations.

In your "found result", $\partial_i$ is used for *both* the map $x\mapsto f(Ax)$ and the map $x\mapsto f(x)$.

It would be helpful to look at the simplest case where $n=1$.

Consider the example $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=f(3x)$. Then the chain rule says that
$$
\partial_1g(x)=\partial_1f(3x)\cdot 3=2(3x)\cdot3=18x
$$

But it is very confusing to write, in the way of your "found result",
$$
\partial_1g(x)=\color{red}{ \partial_1f(3x)}=\color{blue}{ \partial_1f(3x)}\cdot 3=2(3x)\cdot3=18x
$$
Note that the expression in red and blue have totally different meanings.

At least one should write
$$
\partial_1g(x)=\color{red}{ \partial_1(f(3x))}=\color{blue}{ \partial_1f(3x)}\cdot 3=2(3x)\cdot3=18x
$$

Comment: Thanks, your example helped me to unravel the confusion. The result that is meant is: $\partial_i \color{red}{(}f(Ax) \color{red}{)} = \sum_k\partial_k f(Ax) A_{ki}$.

Comment: To emphasize: It's $\partial_k f$ evaluated at $Ax$. Note that you're writing $\partial_i f(Ax)$ to mean something totally different. You have to pay attention to detail or this stuff gets hopelessly confusing. But, yes, with the red parentheses it makes sense.